# UILabel for 3 seconds after UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am using this right now and i worked for a few days than all of a sudden just stopped working so it is now there when i press button till game is over....          - (IBAction)ButtonPausePressed:(id)sender {

```
if(GameOver.hidden == false)
    return;
PauseLabel.hidden = false;
[PauseLabel performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@1 afterDelay:3];

if (GameEnd != true){
    if ([GameUpdate isValid]){
        [GameUpdate invalidate];
        [BirdUpdate invalidate];
    }else{
        BirdUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(UpdateBird)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        GameUpdate = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.025
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(GameUpdate)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using GCD, instead of perform selector. Something like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   PauseLabel.hidden = YES;
});
```